# Show me an simple example of Oracle Streams?

Tags: java, oracle, jms, oracle-streams

I am just getting started with on a project and hope to use Oracle streams.

I am looking for a straight-forward, hello-world type of example using Oracle Streams.  Can you point me to a tutorial or show me an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pretty good resource is the blog: [We Do Streams](http://wedostreams.blogspot.com/)

A good starting point is: [Oracle Streams One Way Table Replication 101](http://wedostreams.blogspot.com/2009/01/oracle-streams-101.html)

Comment: This is an excellent tutorial.  Thanks, it's exactly what I was looking for.  There is a PPT presentation out there claiming to be 'step by step' but it's not very helpful.  The One Way Table Replication 101 is what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do your research about what kind of Streams setup you want to make. For a downstream setup (this means that the capture of changes in the database you use as source, will be made in the destination system) you can follow this simple [guide](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3611536/Data-Replication-Using-Oracle-Downstream-Capture.htm).

You can find details about each step of the setup at [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28321/strms_over.htm)'s site.

Comment: What if the links go down? Could you summarise what they say in your answer to guard against that?

Comment: there are alternatives. You can create multiple capture apply and propagation processes and also define different destinations (search for log_archive_dest_1 ). In case the propagation to a destination fails for whatever reason, another one could start (log_archive_dest_2 with log_archive_dest_state_2 = ALTERNATE) . 
Check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28294/log_arch_dest_param.htm . 

In case you don't need to have a livestream (the same data on both DBs without any delay) then you can recover your system.

Comment: @WaiHaLee - The site is down now, when I needed it :(